# Difference between \relax and % for ending a line

Tags: macros

when would I use one over the other?  Are they the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They're not the same at all: `%` will comment out the rest of the line, including the line break, while `\relax` is just mostly a no-op and you're using that spaces (including line breaks) after control sequences are discarded.

Frankly, I can't see any situation where you'd not want to use `%`.

Comment: Here's one place where you want to \relax instead of %: \relax can be gobbled. % can't. The next live thing after the % will be gobbled.

Comment: In an expanding context you really don't want to use `\relax` just to get rid of spaces!

Comment: @David: point taken, neither can % end a delimited argument because it's removed too early. Can't think why I'd be at the end of the line and unconditionally gobbling something, but maybe that occurs if one doesn't go the "usual" routine of making ^M active.

Answer (score 6):

I think your forgot "a space". When you write  `%` it's after a space or not ? Like Ulrich says `%` and `\relax` are not the same. `%` will comment out the rest of the line but you can put a space before the `%`. Now the problem is to use a `\relax` or a space. I try to find an answer about this question, I read something about this, but I can't find it.

The next example comes from the book  Advanced TexBook by D Salomon :

```
 \def\step{\advance\temp by\ifodd\pageno 1\else2\fi}
```

This macro terminates with a `\fi`. Does it still need a space or a `\relax`? if

The expansion of `\step` gives either `\advance by 1` or `\advance by 2`. After a number a `\relax` is necessary.

```
 \def\step{\advance\temp by\ifodd\pageno 1\else2\fi\relax}
```

The space is not enough because with

```
\def\step{\advance\temp by\ifodd\pageno 1\else2\fi }
```

expansions of \step will not include the space.

Remark : When TeX encounters digits, it expects the number to be followed by an unambiguous terminator (text, space, punctuation). if after the digits there is a command, this command is immediately executed in the attempt to find others digits.

Comment: `\def\step{\advance\temp by\ifodd\pageno1 \else2 \fi}` should work. Mine has one extra token though.

Comment: No you get an error with \def\date{10/06/2011} \par \date \par \the\temp \par \step \date \par \the\temp

Comment: I got no error and the output of `\the\temp` was 0 followed by 1. What error did you get?

Comment: I should point out that when TeX is looking for a number, it looks for several specific things including octal, decimal, and hexadecimal constants. It stops looking for additional numbers (or letters in the case of hex) as soon as it encounters an unexpandable token that isn't one. A space counts.

Comment: I use TeX with   \newcount\temp \temp=0 after `\step \date \par` `\the\temp` gives `110`

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't copy my definition of `\step` correctly then. `tex '\newcount\temp\temp=0 \def\step{\advance\temp by\ifodd\pageno1 \else2 \fi}\def\date{10/06/2011}\step \date \par \showthe\temp\bye'` shows `1`.

Comment: More simple `1. \def\x{12} 2. \count0=\x % 3. \the\count0 ` gives 123. it's the same error

Comment: Your comment is confusing because of the `%` there, but I think I know what you're trying to say. TeX expands macros looking for numbers. My original code does not have the flaw you describe as I was very careful to put spaces after 1 and 2.

Comment: @TH. Ok I understand but you example is different you put a space after 1 and 2 . My (Salomon) example  does not have  space after 1 and 2 so the problem is what to do after \fi : space or `\relax`. With my text ,the answer is relax because the space after `\fi` is not useful

Comment: Yes, I understood. In fact the first and third definition of `\step` in your answer are identical since the space after the `\fi` is ignored when TeX is parsing the replacement text.