# Use of \relax after \ifnum ... \fi construction

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals, plain-tex

I'm reading Malcolm Clark's *A Plain TeX Primer*. On page 111 there's an exercise to define a macro that prints the current time. I've reproduced Clark's answer below:

```
\newcount\minleft
\newcount\timehour
\def\thetime{\timehour=\time
  \divide\timehour by60 %gives 24 hour part of clock
  \minleft=\timehour
  \multiply\minleft by-60 %
  \advance\minleft by\time    %minutes after hour
  \ifnum\time>720\advance\timehour by-12\fi\relax
  \number\timehour:\ifnum\minleft<10 %
                   0\fi\relax\number\minleft
  \ifnum\time>720~p.m.\else~a.m.\fi}
```

My problem is that I don't know what `\relax` is doing in lines 8 and 10 (after each `\fi`). When I use this macro, it prints the time as it's supposed to:

**8:51 p.m.**

If I delete the `\relax` in line 8, I get the time but with the hour missing:

**:51 p.m.**

If I delete the `\relax` in line 10 (and restore the `\relax` in line 8), the macro works again like it did the first time:

**8:51 p.m.**

I naively thought that the `\fi` that ends the `\ifnum` block ends the processing of whatever's going on in the `\ifnum ... \fi`, and that it wouldn't matter whether `\relax` is there or not, in either place. Clearly that's not the case, but I can't figure out what's happening in line 8, and also why the `\relax` *doesn't* seem to be necessary in line 10.

In a different context the author does explain that `\relax` is a "do nothing" command that (in this other context) prevents TeX from treating the expression before the `\relax` and after the `\relax` parts of the same expression. I get that. But concerning `\relax` after an `\fi`, he says:

"The `\relax` is probably not required, but it's always nice to have one in: perhaps an example of 'safe TeX'."

This might be good advice, but it is not enlightening.

I found the following questions about `\relax` on tex.se, but I don't think they answer my question (or at least I'm not smart enough to figure it out):

[What is the difference between \relax and {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and)

[What does \relax do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96501/what-does-relax-do)

[Difference between \relax and % for ending a line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20669/difference-between-relax-and-for-ending-a-line)

[Normal \relax vs. frozen \relax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/normal-relax-vs-frozen-relax)

So, what is `\relax` actually doing in this macro?

Comment: The `\relax` acts as a delimiter for any register evaluation. (A space token does this, too.) I’m sure we have some good Q&As on that … [Do assignments need to be appended by % to remove the trailing white spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107650) only scratches the surface.

Comment: Is the `\relax` acting as a delimiter for a register evaluation here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know this primer, but I am a little leery of any book that claims to be instructional but cheerfully advises you to do something "just in case".  There is always a reason; in this case, the reason is one of the characteristic quirks of TeX.

The problem is not so much the `\ifnum` as the `\advance`.  The amount by which you are to advance is scanned for by TeX in an oppositely-greedy fashion: it goes as far as possible into the input stream, expanding all the way, until it encounters a primitive quantity that cannot be part of a number.  Then it takes what it found as the operand.  Here is how the expression

```
\ifnum\time>720\advance\timehour by-12\fi%\relax
  \number\timehour:
```

is parsed.  First, it checks `\time` against `720`, and if so begins to execute `\advance`.  This reads `-12` and then *continues* reading.  Now, the thing you were missing here is that `\fi` is *not* syntactical: that is, it is *still* in the input stream at this point, not having been removed when TeX processed the `\ifnum`.  And it's expandable.  Expanding it does terminate the conditional, but there is no kind of lexical scope for the branches, so expansion continues past `\fi` and reaches `\number\timehour`, which is an expandable quantity that becomes whatever number `\timehour` currently is.  Then comes the `:`, and this is non-expandable and non-numerical, so scanning stops.

The result is that, if `\time > 720`, we advance `\timehour` by the value `-12<value of \timehour before advancing>`.  That whole number is absorbed, though after advancing it is basically thrown away since the only piece of code actually using `\timehour` has been removed.  On the contrary, if the `\relax` were not commented, since it is *not* expandable, it would kill the expansion immediately after `\fi` and `\number\timehour` would not be thrown away; since it is a no-op, it has no other effect.  This explains why, in its absence, the hour disappears from the output and only the colon remains.

I don't think this is great style.  It detaches the `\relax` from the thing that it's protecting.  Probably better is to write

```
\ifnum\time>720\advance\timehour by-12\relax\fi
  \number\timehour:
```

so the entire phrase `\advance \timehour by -12\relax` is a single operation.  You can also just put a space after the `-12`, but be careful that it's not thrown away carelessly; TeX's blase attitude towards spaces lends itself to lots of programming glitches (like any language feature that makes it easy to write code in a colloquial rather than a strict formal style).

Comment: Good answer can do with an example, such as `\newcount\anumber
\anumber=20
\ifnum\anumber>10\advance\anumber by\fi22
\the\anumber`

Comment: Note that TeX's formal syntax allows exactly one optional space to terminate a number, and that this will be gobbled by expansion, but that `\relax` is just a 'non-expandable' stopper. Thus inside an `\edef` using a space to terminate a number will give a 'clean' result but a `\relax` will still be there. As a result, I'd (weakly) favour a space.

Comment: @JosephWright I'd strongly favor a space instead of `\relax` in this case. Not a big difference, because it's in an `\advance` context, but in several other cases a space *is* the correct token.

Comment: @egreg As I said, I think a space is also preferable, but perhaps not as strongly as you (this is not expandable so there is no issue with a stray `\relax).

Comment: @JosephWright  using `12\space\fi` rather than `12\fi\relax` or `12 \fi` is also an option. The `\space` is less likely to be lost in code reshuffling than a blank, and contrarily to `\relax` it does not stay there, it truly disappears after expanding to the space token which terminates the number.