# Reset counter via macro with \ifcase in Plain

Tags: macros, conditionals, counters, plain-tex

I am not able to reset a counter to zero using a macro in Plain TeX.

This code uses `\ifcase` and the counter `animalnum` to output one of a list of animal names, incrementing the counter each time it is called so that next call will produce the subsequent name in the list. If it has been called more than a maximum number, it outputs an error message.

The command `\resetanimalnum` is supposed to set the counter back to zero and start the list over, but for some reason it doesn't work as expected.

**Why does the counter behave this way and I how can I fix it?**

```
\newcount\animalnum

\def\nextanimal{%                                                                                                                                                                              
  \ifcase\animalnum%                                                                                                                                                                           
    \animalI\or
    \animalII\or
    \animalIII%                                                                                                                                                                                
  \fi%                                                                                                                                                                                         
  \ifnum\animalnum > 2
    \exclaim%                                                                                                                                                                                  
  \fi%                                                                                                                                                                                         
  \advance\animalnum by 1%                                                                                                                                                                     
}

\def\resetanimalnum{\animalnum=0}

\def\animalI   {Lions}
\def\animalII  {Tigers}
\def\animalIII {Bears}
\def\exclaim   {Oh my!}

\nextanimal\ \nextanimal\ \nextanimal\ \nextanimal

\resetanimalnum\nextanimal\ \nextanimal

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I think, `\resetanimalnum` is the culprit. If you put `\nextanimal` into the next line, it works

Comment: try `\def\resetanimalnum{\animalnum=0\relax}`

Comment: you can replace `\fi%                                                                                                                                                                                         
  \ifnum\animalnum > 2` with `\else`

Comment: @touhami: I just wanted to suggest the same with `\relax`, but I don't know why this must be this way

Comment: @touhami @ChristianHupfer Yes, that works (and yes, `\else` is better)! But why does TeX not reset the counter without the `\relax` (or a space)?

Comment: if tex is trying to determine the value of a counter, it keeps going until it definitively finds something non-numeric.  so a space or `\relax` will stop the parsing of `\animalnum=0`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Oh, I didn't see your comment while I was answering

Comment: There are a number of references to this on the site. Here's one which includes a reference elsewhere as well: [Use of `\relax` after `\ifnum` … `\fi` construction](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137207/5764)

Comment: “Missing required space” syndrome!

Comment: @werner the question doesn't ask about relax and the accepted answer doesn't use \relax so i wouldn't have used the gold badge hammer to close it as a dup of a question about relax.

Comment: @barbarabeeton ^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: A question doesn't have to ask about something to be a duplicate. Typically people don't know what the problem is, hence their question. It's commonly the *answer* that identifies a duplicate (see my thought process in [How to search for duplicates and handle them?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6321/5764)). Also, the *accepted* answer is just that, it's the answer that helped the OP most, but there could be other answers that answer the question to *this* one. That's why you may have accepted answers being outscored by other answers. You *can* vote to re-open, of course.

Comment: @Werner yes but the referenced question can only have answers about \relax but this one \relax is usually not the best solution so it just isn't a duplicate at all, really. I voted to re-open (actually it opened straight away, didn't know it would do that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- okay, you've given a cogent counter-argument in your answer, and i've removed my comment.  (i still think the referenced answer contains an excellent explanation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the main culprits are the incorrect use of `%` after the 1 which prevents the 1 being terminated, and the lack of a space after 0. In some cases you can terminate a number with `\relax` but that leaves a `\relax` in the token stream which is not always desirable, a space is absorbed as part of the number.

```
\newcount\animalnum

\def\nextanimal{%
  \ifcase\animalnum
    \animalI\or
    \animalII\or
    \animalIII
  \fi
  \ifnum\animalnum > 2
    \exclaim
  \fi
  \advance\animalnum by 1
}

\def\resetanimalnum{\animalnum=0 }

\def\animalI   {Lions}
\def\animalII  {Tigers}
\def\animalIII {Bears}
\def\exclaim   {Oh my!}

\nextanimal\ \nextanimal\ \nextanimal\ \nextanimal

\resetanimalnum\nextanimal\ \nextanimal

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you -- this explains it completely. Is it also true that I should more properly use `\else` instead of the `\ifnum` construction?

Comment: @AndrewCashner I saw that comment on the other answer but they are not equivalent so it depends what you want if you go ifcase or, or, or ...else fiexclaim then you either get an animal or exclaim. if you go ifcase of or or fi \ifnum exclaim fi  then you get an animal and then exclaim if the test number is bigger than 2 so you may get an animal and an exclaim

Answer (score 2):

It's stated (somehow) in the `TeX by Topic` book (page 66)

TeX can expand too far in case of counter evaluation and will try find something non-numerical, i.e. it might absorb and expand the next statement `\nextanimal` which is a fault here.

If `\relax` is inserted, this can be stopped. (The `\relax` is not mentioned on that page, but the expansion can be stopped with `\relax` then.

A one-time solution would be to place a newline between `\resetanimalnum` and the next call to `\nextanimal`, but this might get tedious.

```
\newcount\animalnum

\def\nextanimal{%
    \ifcase\animalnum%                                                                                                                                      
    \animalI\or
    \animalII\or
    \animalIII%                                                                                                                                             
    \fi%
    \ifnum\animalnum > 2
    \exclaim%
    \fi%
    \advance\animalnum by 1%
}

\def\resetanimalnum{\animalnum=0\relax}%

\def\animalI   {Lions}
\def\animalII  {Tigers}
\def\animalIII {Bears}
\def\exclaim   {Oh my!}

\nextanimal\ \nextanimal\ \nextanimal\ \nextanimal

\resetanimalnum\nextanimal\ \nextanimal

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: `\ifcase\animalnum<0>\or<1>\or<2>\else\exclaim\fi` is “more correct”.