Help with Missing number, treated as zero and Missing = inserted for \ifnum, for code that works
I'm trying to create a function with tikz that can create some points around a circle. The document can be rendered, and everything look fine, but I am still getting some errors I can't figure out how to solve.
Hope someone can help me.
These are the errors:
Missing number, treated as zero.
Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
Missing number, treated as zero.
This is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\drawCirclePoints}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle, draw}]
        \newcommand{\templ}{}
        \foreach \m/\n in #2 {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{0}
            \foreach \k in \templ {
                \ifnum\m=\k
                    \pgfmathparse{\c + 1}
                    \global\let\c\pgfmathresult
                \fi
            }
            \ifnum\c=0
                \xappto\templ{,\m}
            \fi
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{0}
            \foreach \k in \templ {
                \ifnum\n=\k
                    \pgfmathparse{\c + 1}
                    \global\let\c\pgfmathresult
                \fi
            }
            \ifnum\c=0
                \xappto\templ{,\n}
            \fi
        };
        \StrCount{\templ}{,}[\numofelem]
        \StrBehind[1]{\templ}{,}[\mytail]%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{0}
        \foreach \i in \mytail {
            \pgfmathparse{\l + 1}
            \global\let\l\pgfmathresult
        };
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{360 / (\l)}
        \draw[help lines] (-#1, -#1) grid (#1, #1);
        \foreach \i [count=\k from 0] in \mytail {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{#1 * cos(\k * \a + 90)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{#1 * sin(\k * \a + 90)}
            \node (\i) at (\x, \y) {\i};
        };
        \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (#1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\drawCirclePoints{4}{{1/2,2/4,4/1}}
\end{document}


Would it be easier to use polar coordinates? E.g. \node at (60:#1) {quack};

If you get errors the function doesn't work. There is only the possibility to continue building to spot more errors. After you got a single error message the resulting PDF should only be handled as a resource to find errors and not for anything else.

"," in \xappto\templ{,\m} causes the first error. The l3tl package of the LaTeX3 bundle offers \tl_put_right documentation interface3

Welcome to TeX.SE!

It should be noted that \m. \n, \k etc are macros, not counts.  There may be some confusion with the parser on where to stop adding digits.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137207/use-of-relax-after-ifnum-fi-construction

For what I understand, the first arg is the radius, but in the second arg, what the values stand for?

What are you trying to achieve? What do the entries in the list 1/2, 2/4, 4/1 stand for? There are easier ways to place a number of nodes in a circle.

Even though it doesn't appear to be an issue here, you should be careful mixing \pgfmathparse/\pgfmathsetmacro with \ifnum:
PGFMath does not always return an integer  but \ifnum needs an integer number.
Replace \pgfmathsetmacro with \pgfmathtruncatemacro or include the int functions around the argument of \pgfmathparse.
More importantly, every list you build starts with a ,, so the very first element of the \templ loops is an empty macro which is not a number which trips up \ifnum:
\ifnum=0

leads to the missing number error.
You need to remove the first , inside the loops before \templ gets used as the \foreach list.

I'll implement a \xapptoorstartlist macro that tests whether its first argument is \empty and initiates or appends to the list accordingly. Since \empty is not a \long macro, I've also initiated \templ as a not-long macro (by using the * with `\newcommand*).
Many packages and L3 as well provide better ways to deal with lists, you'll find plenty of examples on this site.
As a precaution, I've also replaced all \pgfmathparses and \pgfmathsetmacros with \pgfmathtruncatemacros so that they will always return integer numbers for \ifnum.
I'm also replaced the evaluation of x and y values by using the polar coordinate specification.
Try to avoid using control sequences like \c (¸) and \l (ł) at least globally since these actually are defined already.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*\xapptoorstartlist[2]{%
  \ifx#1\empty
    \global\let#1#2%
  \else
    \xappto#1{,#2}%
  \fi}
\newcommand{\drawCirclePoints}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle, draw}]
  \newcommand*\templ{}
  \foreach \m/\n in #2 {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\c}{0}
    \foreach \k in \templ {
      \ifnum\m=\k
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\c}{\c + 1}
        \global\let\c\c
      \fi
    }
    \ifnum\c=0 \xapptoorstartlist\templ\m \fi
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\c}{0}
    \foreach \k in \templ {
      \ifnum\n=\k
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\c}{\c + 1}
        \global\let\c\c
      \fi
    }
    \ifnum\c=0 \xapptoorstartlist\templ\n \fi
  }
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\l}{0}
  \foreach \i in \templ {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\l}{\l + 1}
    \global\let\l\l
  }
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{360 / (\l)}
  \draw[help lines] (-#1, -#1) grid (#1, #1);
  \foreach \i [count=\k from 0] in \templ
    \node (\i) at (\k*\a+90:{#1}) {\i};
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (#1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\drawCirclePoints{4}{{1/2,2/4,4/1}}
\end{document}


It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. It is very easy to just count the entries of a list like 1, 2, 4 -- I will be using TikZ on-board utilities like the \foreach powered .list handler here but plenty of other solutions exist --, and then use that list again to place the nodes.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{
  /utils/count list/.code 2 args=\def\pgfmathresult{0}%
    \pgfkeys{/utils/@count list/.list={#1}}\let#2\pgfmathresult,
  /utils/@count list/.code=\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathresult+1}}}
\newcommand{\drawCirclePoints}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    nodes={draw, circle},
    /utils/count list={#2}{\tikzlistlength}]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) circle[radius={#1}];
  \foreach[count=\i from 0] \v in {#2}
    \node (\v) at (90+360/\tikzlistlength*\i:{#1}) {$\v$};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\drawCirclePoints{4}{1, 2, 4}
\end{document}

Output

